# Why does this code for not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

This code contains javascript to open a new window and access a url on submit. There seems to be some issue creating element in IE 11 since it opens a blank page. This code works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But does not in Internet Explorer 11.

```
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
                        var frm = document.createElement('form');
                        frm.setAttribute("action", serverUrl);
                        frm.setAttribute("name", "mstr");
                        var hiddenInput;

                         for ( var prop in myData ) {
                            if( myData.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                                hiddenInput =  document.createElement('input');
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute("name", prop);
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", myData[prop]);
                                frm.appendChild(hiddenInput);
                            }
                        }

                        frm.setAttribute("method", "post");
                        ifr.appendChild(frm);

                        var new_window = window.open();
                        $(new_window.document.body).append(ifr);
                        frm.submit();
```

Comment: ever heard of jquery, a library for cross-browser consistency? :) P.s. you're using jquery to append the iframe html, yet you are not using it to create elements...

Comment: hehe I tried using jquery too but just doesnt seem to work. Could you please post some code

Comment: Post your error. F12 -> Console

Comment: IE doesn't let you to append elements from a different document. Create an `onload` handler for `frm`, and create the new elements to `frm`'s document.

Comment: The argument 'type' was of type 'String' but is required to be of type 'Number'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have made the form submit to new window with target blank instead of creating and opening a new window this worked. Thank you so much for all replies!